# How to register on Jetstream via Postman (API)

Tags: laravel, api, postman, laravel-jetstream

[image: Postman]

First step: I am posting data via Postman on the api/reg

[image: api.php]

Second step: I am getting perfectly all the sent data

Third step: nothing lol, I can't get to this 3rd step, what to do to send this data to database how Jetstream does?[image: CreateUser]

Somehow I found this `CreateNewUser.php` and via `dd()` I found out that my regular blade register information is coming to this point, but from where is it coming, and where is it going after is a mystery, There is no any information on the internet, so I am getting the register data (name,email...) in my Laravel project, somewhere AGAIN in my Laravel project there is some mechanism that upgrades (adds tokens etc...) and sends my data to database, how to connect that two things to each other? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Jetstream is not intended to be used in this manner, if you want to expose an API you should use something like [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) or [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport). Sanctum is more lgihtwieght and has simpler workflow, Passport is heavier and provides a full oauth workflow which might be overkill in some scenarios. Both of these solutions use token authentication with Jetstream does not provide out of the box.

That said, to answer you question of how this all works.

Jetstream uses [Laravel Fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) as its web authentication provider. It comes with a bunch of routes predefined, all of which you can see using `php artisan route:list --compact`. The route you're interested in is the `POST /register` route which is mapped to `Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController@store`. When the registration form is submitted, the data is sent to that controller/method. The method expects two parameters, a `Request` object and a `CreatesNewUsers` object, both of which are injected by Laravels [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container).

The `CreatesNewUsers` object that is passed to the `store` method, is an instance of the `CreateNewUser` class you've found in `App\Actions\Fortify` which then performs the action of registering a new user. If you were to modify the structure of your `User` class, such as adding a phone number for example, you would need to edit `CreateNewUser` to include that new requirement if it was required when a user registers.

Here is a nice tutorial on how to [Build a Restful API in PHP with Laravel Sanctum](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-restful-api-php-laravel-sanctum).